# Is there a convenient way to convert a JSON-like map[string]interface{} to struct , and vice versa, with tags in Go?

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

Suppose I have a Go struct, complete with JSON tags:

```
type Person struct {
    Name    string   `json:"name"`
    Age     int      `json:"age,omitifempty"`
    Flags   []string `json:"-"`
}

p := Person{ Name: "Bob", Age: 36, Flags: []string{"employed","father"} }
```

Now I want to convert this to a generic `map[string]interface{}`, such as I might receive from a REST API via JSON:

```
p2 := map[string]interface{}{
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 36,
}
```

I have devised the following function to accomplish this using the [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json) package. But the intermediate step of a JSON string seems unnecessary and wasteful.

```
func ConvertJSONObject(input, output interface{}) error {
    encoded, err := json.Marshal(input)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(encoded, output)
}
```

Now I can do this:

```
var p2 map[string]interface{}
ConvertJSONObject(p, &p2)
```

As an added bonus, the same function works in reverse, to turn a `map[string]interface{}` into a populated struct:

```
var p Person
ConvertJSONObject(p2, &p)
```

Is there a simpler solution, which honors tags in the roughly the same way the json package does?

Comment: You can also directly marshal the struct without converting to map[string]interface{} before. The same applies for unmarshaling. I don't quite understand why you would want/need to take the detour over the map

Comment: @tike: Yes, if I have JSON-formatted data. I don't. This question is about not having to use JSON as the intermediate step.

Comment: So why do you need to convert the struct to map in the first place?

Comment: I need to interface with an API that expects an arbitrary structure, but I don't want to have to pass `map[string]interface{}` all over the place in my code.

Comment: Does API mean a function in some library you use, which accepts only map[string]interface{} as argument? Just to be clear :-)

Comment: @tike: Basically. But don't get hung up on that detail. I've actually been using this pattern in a number of projects with slightly different APIs and needs , and just want to find a better solution.

Comment: I know I can just re-implement what the `json` package does with reflection to read the tags... and that's probably what I will do.  But I was hoping for something simpler, which wouldn't require my own, hairy utility functions

Comment: https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure ?

Comment: @elithrar: That looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: @CodingPickle: That's similar, but seems to ignore tags, which I would consider a vital part of my question.